# ASP.NET: Async execute callback on slower running Task when controller exits on fast running task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a ASP.NET controller that internally calls an API and cache for answers and returns the answer from the first task completed. In general, API is much slower than cache and cache returns in 50ms while API returns in 2s at the 95th percentile.

**Requirements:**

1. Return answer from cache immediately if available. Otherwise wait for API and return available/empty response as the case maybe.
2. Once API call completes, we update the cache with the new answer if available.

**Problem:**
How to await API call and write to cache in a background thread without blocking controller?

Current flow:

```
Task<string>[] getDataTasks = new Task<string>[]
{
    getDataFromAPI(),
    getDataFromCache()
};

var finishedTaskIndex = Task.WaitAny(getDataTasks);
var response = getDataTasks[finishedTaskIndex].Result;

if (finishedTaskIndex == 1 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
{          
      response = await getDataTasks[0];
      writeToCacheTask(response); //fire and forget, this is non-blocking
}

**//Problem :- How to await for response from API and write to cache in a non-blocking manner** THIS DOES NOT WORK
Task.Run(async () =>
{
     var apiResponse = await getDataTasks[0];
     writeToCacheTask(apiResponse);
});

return response;
```

In the above, even though I am using a new thread to await the api call independent of the main thread, it does not work.

**Does not work**
Tried using ContinueWith on the Task with a callback with TaskContinuationOptions = ExecuteSynchronously as this continues on the same thread the task was invoked on. But I am perhaps understanding it wrongly.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    return await getDataTasks[0];
}).ContinueWith(this.CallBack, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
```

**Works: Using delegate handlers**

```
// private members of controller
private delegate string DelegateHandler();

private string getDataFromAPISync()
{
   return getDataFromAPI().GetAwaiter().GetResults();
}

private string getDataFromCacheSync()
{
   return getDataFromCache().GetAwaiter().GetResults();
}

private void CallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   var apiResponse = apiInvoker.EndInvoke(ar);
   writeToCacheTask(apiResponse);
}
```

```
// In controller
var apiInvoker = new DelegateHandler(this.getDataFromAPISync)
var cacheInvoker = new DelegateHandler(this.getDataFromCacheSync)

IAsyncResult apiResults = apiInvoker.BeginInvoke(this.CallBack, null);
IAsyncResult cacheResults = cacheInvoker.BeginInvoke(null, null);

var handles = new WaitHandle[]
{
   apiResults.AsyncWaitHandle,
   cacheResults.AsyncWaitHandle
}

WaitHandle.WaitAny(handles);

if (cacheResults.IsCompleted)
{
   return cacheInvoker.EndInvoke(ar);
}

return apiInvoker.EndInvoke(ar);
```

When I am using delegate handler, it looks like the background thread used to make the api call, is used to handle the callback as well and only once callback is completed it is killed.

**How to do the same using the Task library?**

Comment: Which version of ASP are you using? See [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.queuebackgroundworkitem?view=netframework-4.8) or [HttpResponse.OnCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.oncompleted?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: `it does not work.` What _specifically_ isn't working?

Comment: Also see [Implement background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice).

Comment: Please share `writeToCacheTask`.

Comment: Also pay attention to the [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) and [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) libraries.

Comment: ASP.NET can kill background thread at any time. So you second approach may fail.

Comment: But why though? No client is going to notice the difference between 2s & 2s+50ms. Just wait for the cache answer, then call the slow api; update the cache & return the answer. Why would you want to increase the load on your backend by hitting the real api on every cache hit?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - The author wants to return the result immediately, if it is in the cache, and not wait for 2 seconds.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov. We are using .net 4.5.2. Let me look at your suggestions and get back, but I have tried the delegate handler solution and from logs I do see that the callback is called every single time. So there must be a Task based solution too.

Comment: @mjwills: The call -> writeToCacheTask is not hit. The writeDataToCache calls azure table method ExecuteAsync after some data transformation. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executeasync). I do not wait for the task to complete and do not care if it succeeds. From logs, it mostly succeeds.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `writeToCacheTask`, sure you can use a background service. But (IMHO)  only read from one, not the other `(await getDataFromCache()) ?? (await getDataFromAPI());`. It's also possible (though ugly, and maybe fragile) to block disposing a scoped service until the work is complete.